# Is there a way I can connect to my computer through a domain or IP that bypasses a router? Similar to how Team Viewer does screen sharing?

Tags: internet, proxy, web, hosting

So, I want to show some people a rails app I've been working on, And I can't get passed the firewall on the router (it's not mine / the ISP won't let us have access to it).

So, is there some sort of service that will act as a middle-man (similar to how the Team Viewer servers act as a bridge, connecting viewer and host), such that my rails server can be accessed by the public?

Answer (score 1):

No, one way or another your router will need to allow incoming connections if you want the public to see something on the internal network without you initiating the connection from the inside.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search a provider for "Remote Port Forwarding", usually some providers of VPN connections offer that kind of service.

If you have access to your own Linux Server on the Internet you can configure your own remote port forwarding with just a ssh session but for better security you should use a VPN provider.